# использование expression language

Tags: java, jsp

Есть таблица, которая выводит записи, и в ней отображается состояние прикрепленного файла. Задача: я хочу задать атрибут в контролере, который при условии повреждения файла на сервере, будет в строке с нужным id выводить этот атрибут. Проблема в том, что имя атрибута я делаю динамическим, и ни как не могу его отловить в jsp

Часть таблицы, где мне нужно отловить атрибут:

```
 <td>

  <c:if test="${empty errorFile}">
     <i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </c:if>


  <c:if test="${not empty errorFile}">

     <c:out value="${errorFile}"></c:out>
  </c:if>
</td>
```

Контроллер:

```
for (Task task : taskList) {
                idTask = task.getId();
                int stateFile = task.getStateFile();


                if (stateFile == 1) {
                    try {
                        String fileStr = AbstractController.getFileNameWithPath(String.valueOf(idTask));
                        File file = new File(fileStr);

                        AbstractController.checkIsFile(file);
                    } catch (FileException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        request.setAttribute("errorFile" + idTask, "errorFile" + idTask);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Контроллер:

```
Set<Long> errors = new HashSet<>();
for (Task task : taskList) {
    ...
                } catch (FileException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    errors.add(idTask);
                }
    ...
}
request.setAttribute("errorFiles", errors);
```

Шаблон:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${ someFiles }">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <c:if test="${ errorFiles.contains(item.id) }">
        <c:out value="${ item.id }" />
      </c:if>
    </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: спасибо, большое